# Appium: onDestroy() never called after tests

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-android

I am a beginner to test automation and using **Appium** to automate some E2E tests for a **native Android** application. My test files are written in Java.

I noticed that **after** test methods within a test class the app **does not properly** close, i. e. call **onDestroy()** or **onPause()**. I noticed that because I store some data in the SharedPreferences (in onDestroy() & onPause()) and the file stays untouched or does not get created at all.

I tried various combinations of setting the Desired Capability noReset to true/false and invoking driver.quit() or driver.closeApp in the @AfterMethod.

I run the test on an AVD (Pixel 2). onResume() and onCreate() seem to get called properly.

My only solution as of now would be writing the data into the file at another point but I feel like it is really hacky and only serves the purpose of making the test work.

Therefore I would really appreciate some help!

THANKS

This should be the relevant code:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setup () throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities caps caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "device");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0");
    caps.setCapability("skipUnlock","true");
    caps.setCapability("noReset",false);
    caps.setCapability("fullReset",true);
    caps.setCapability("app", "/path/to/my/app-debug.apk");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new 
    URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),caps);
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
}

@Test 
public void someTest() {
}
@Test 
public void anotherTest() {
}

@AfterMethod
public void teardown(){

    driver.closeApp();
}
```

EDIT:

I assumed that maybe the storing of the SharedPreferences via `commit()`is somehow intervened by Appium and changed it to the asynchronous call `apply()`. However that did not turn out to be the solution and led to the same outcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show us a code snippet of your solution.

Comment: @cSteusloff Thank you! Sorry for not including it initially, I added a code snippet to my question.